# Does it suffice to know the pronounciation of a name without its spelling?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, grammar-dikduk

Today, I asked a friend what his Hebrew name is to daven for him. He said his full name but did not know the spelling of his mother's name (Perel).

This made me wonder: Is there any relevance to the spelling of someone's name when praying for them? Does it make any difference if I don't know how to spell it, as long as I know how to pronounce it?

Comment: Names are given verbally. And there are often different spellings of the same name, even in Torah.

Comment: Moshe did not use Miriam's name when praying that she be healed ([Numbers 12:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Spelling/pronunciation can't be as important as having the right person in mind.

Comment: @Deuteronomy See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38994/6592

Comment: @shmosel ideally yes, one has the name. However it is clearly not an absolute requirement, nor an impediment to the prayer being enunciated and accepted.